# How should I pass parameters to the Autofac container for auto dependency resolution via Autofac.Dependency injection lib

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, autofac, asp.net-core-mvc-2.1

Here is the problem. I'm currently using Autofac to resolve all the dependencies with TypedParameters in my AspNetCore MVC app, but I think I'm do something wrong and I can do it cleaner.

Below are following code samples

- Configuration for the services.
- Sample repository to inject
- Current method used
- What i want to do

**Configuration:**

```
public static void Configure(IConfiguration cfg,IServiceCollection services)
    {
        /// some code is skipped here. Module registrant is just pulling out 
        /// the services from dlls and register them. 
        ioCBuilder.Populate(services);
        ioCBuilder.RegisterModule(new ModuleRegistrant(cfg, registrantOptions));

        IoCHelper.Container = ioCBuilder.Build();
    }
```

**Sample Repository:**

```
public class PriorityRepository: IPriorityRepository   
{
    public PriorityRepository(DbContext db)
    {
        Db = db;
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public Priority GetDefault()
    {
        return Db.Set<Priority>().SingleOrDefault(it => it.IsDefault);
    }
}
```

**Currently I get Repository with following:**

```
public class PriorityController: Controller
{
    public PriorityController(TestContext db)
    {  
       var ctxParam = new TypedParameter(typeof(DbContext), db);
       PriorityRepository = IoCHelper.Container.Resolve<IPriorityRepository>(ctxParam);  
    }
    public IPriorityRepository PriorityRepository { get; set;} 
}
```

**I want it to be something like that**

```
public class PriorityController: Controller
    {
        public PriorityController(IPriorityRepository priorityRepo)
        {  
           PriorityRepository = priorityRepo;
        }
        public IPriorityRepository PriorityRepository { get; set;} 
    }
```

So basically the question is: How do I inject the already registered types which has slightly different type(more abstract) in the constructor?

Comment: Hi, I'm a bit confused about your question. Is your question reflected in the last snippet of code provided? Because that last snippet looks correct. What do you mean by "more abstract" registered types?

Comment: If you mean `IPriorityRepository` and you registered the only one implementation of this interface then you don't need to do anything, it should work out of the box.

Comment: I have registered dependency `TestDbContext` which inherits the `DbContext`. The Implementation of `IPrioriryRepository -> PriorityRepository `accepts the parameter DbContext. It will work with parameterless constructor, but It is not working with the constructor with params. So I have the question: how to do, so I just inject the repository without calling the `Context.Resolve` method in Autofac

Answer (score 0):

The `Func` is used to resolve parameterized dependencies in Autofac.

Kindly go through the link https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html#parameterized-instantiation-func-x-y-b for implementation details and other available options.